# <nolink> top items rendered as <a> and remain clickable (give page refresh)

Tags: navigation

I have a TB megamenu (8.x-1.x-dev) with a few top-level (parent) items that are not links, they should just trigger the submenu to drop down.

According to the documentation I could find, links marked as `<nolink>` or `route:nolink` will be rendered as `<span>` rather than `<a>` so styling can be retained, but they can't clicked, and submenus should still be toggled.

However, both `<nolink>` and `route:nolink` are still rendered as `<a>`, causing a page refresh when clicked.

I have tried adding the `nolink` definition as a special menu item under (A) admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu, and in (B) the tb mega menu settings at admin/structure/tb-megamenu/main-menu, but nothing helps:

- When adding `nolink` to the Drupal menu link (A), it leaves the link empty, but you get the page refresh when you click it. Submenu does unfold.
- When adding `nolink` to the TB Megamenu link (B), it leaves the link empty, no page refresh as it now activates a css class that says `.nolink {pointer-events:none;}`, but button goes dead, and submenu does NOT unfold.

When on mobile, all menu items with children do unfold the submenu, don't trigger a page refresh; it's that behaviour I'd love to be able to have in desktop/laptop view too. (Even better if there is a switch "active link yes/no" or similar, so I can decide per button?)

Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: If you're using the dev version of a module and the issue is specific to the module, you should post in the module's issue queue, not here.  Particularly if what you have found may be a bug with the module.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I did (https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu/issues/3181543) but no answer (yet) - so based on previous very good experience here and a bit of hurry to get this working on a project that needs to go live, I decided to post here as well 

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report or support request to a third-party dependency hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere and must be submitted to the mentioned module's [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/tb_megamenu) to keep fixes at a central place and not here on Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 1):

How are you getting those to save?

It should be `route:<nolink>`. Test that it works on a regular menu before trying the additional module to avoid confusion about what might be happening.

Comment: Yes, I tried `route:<nolink>` as well as `<nolink>` in the normal Drupal menu. That does remove the content of the `<a href="foo.html" class="foo...`, so you end up with `<a href class="foo...`, that is a blank href without any link behind it.

Comment: That's not what I get with `route:<nolink>`, I get a `span` within `li`, no anchor.